# Leverage Browser Caching for third party files - Google Page Speed Insights

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, mod-expires

Though there are similar questions on the subject.
But it doesn't address the issue I am facing.

I am getting the same suggestions for leverage browser caching.

The suggestion I am receiving is for third party files like the one below, over which I don't have a control.

```
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js (20 minutes)
http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?_=1484083656965 (30 minutes)
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js?_=1484083656964 (30 minutes)
http://mywebsolutions.co.in/…element/captcha/image.php?foo=1254288041 (60 minutes)
```

Any suggestion how I can increase the expiry time for these files?
Other answers doesn't address the problem

Comment: You need to use a `cron` to fix this issue. See my answer on this question on how to fix it: [Leverage Browser Caching for 3rd party JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js/38377857#38377857).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leverage browser caching for 3rd party JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js)

Comment: @thickguru - you have advised in that answer to use cron, but have not elaborated on this, how `cron` can help rid you from this problem. By `cron` I understand to run a `cron` sceduled task from server. is it a different `cron`. Thanks

Comment: the point of using a `cron` is to load the JS locally, currently you're loading them externally which is why you're having this issue. If you load them locally then your Leverage browser caching will work with all of the files. You can also set the JS files up with auto-updating, which is also included in the other answer, hope that helps :)