# How to leverage browser cache in moodle

Tags: php, .htaccess, moodle, pagespeed

I have added the following code in the .htaccess file present in the root directory but it is not doing anything.How to leverage cache properly?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but it is not extensive enough. Try using the code below, this covers every aspect of your Leverage Browser Caching. Except for external files.:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

## IMAGES ##
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

## CSS ##
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

## HTML ##
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"

## JAVASCRIPT ##
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</ifModule>
```

If you also want to cache external files, then see the answer to this: [Leverage Browser Caching for 3rd Party JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js/38377857#38377857)