# Speed up wordpress site on google platform

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment, google-search-console

Can anyone help me out on how I could speed up a WordPress website in desktop?

It rating is 71 at the moment and in mobile it's 55 which is unacceptable.
Take a look at the screen shot.

How to get rid of leverage browser cache?
I've used minified js, css and compressed the images.

[image]

Comment: can you share website link

Comment: it's mentiond in the screen shot second link

Comment: The resources you've shown in your screen shot are external JavaScript files. These cannot be cached using normal methods. Check out my answer to this question: [Leverage Browser Caching for 3rd party JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js/38377857#38377857). It will answer and fix your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leverage browser caching for 3rd party JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to arrange 5 plugins.
Here is the plugins name that you have to need for that (wp-rocket, wp-optimize, smush pro, and wp Humminbird also.

You should use those plugin for increase your google speed up

Comment: maybe you could include in your answer some documentation or information as to why these plugins are necessary and how they would help :)