# Leverage browser caching on script SRC

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I keep getting a 'leverage browser caching' error when I running pagespeed insight

This is what it complains about -

```
 <script src="https://company.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary? 
 orderby=published&max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"> 
 </script>
```

I've tried settting a fe thing in the .htaccess file but nothing seems to work -

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /orderby(.*)">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31535999, public"
</If>
```

Any help to fix this would be greatly appriciated. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leverage browser caching for 3rd party JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376871/leverage-browser-caching-for-3rd-party-js)

Comment: You can't cache it because you're trying to cache an external file. See the duplicate that I just tagged. That will help you fix your problem :)